After the Pope's criticism of US Presidential candidate Harris and Trump, have they or the Democrat and Republican party released any statements?

Pope Francis on Friday criticized Donald Trump over his plan to deport millions of immigrants and Kamala Harris over her stance supporting abortion rights ... “You must choose the lesser evil,” he continued. “Who is the lesser evil? That lady, or that gentleman? I don’t know. Everyone, in conscience, [has to] think and do this.” (Pope criticizes Harris and Trump and tells US Catholics to choose ‘lesser evil’)
“Both are against life: the one that throws out migrants and the one that kills children,” Francis said. - (Pope Says Both Trump and Harris Are ‘Against Life’)

Did the candidates or anyone from the Presidential campaign and / or the US political parties release any statement to counter the Pope's criticism and / or to sway the Catholic American voters to support them?

This is pretty similar to what he said in 2016 BTW, albeit perhaps more over this time https://www.reuters.com/article/world/study-pray-vote-pope-tells-americans-ahead-of-elections-idUSKCN12308J/ One might look then to see if there was any direct pushback then, although I suspect there wasn't because reminding Catholics of the disagreement probably doesn't work too well.

Actually, Trump did push back then: "Last February, while returning from Mexico, the pope was asked if U.S. Catholics could vote for someone with Trump's views on immigration, particularly on the candidate's promise to build a wall at the border with Mexico.
He said a person with such views was "not Christian."
Trump struck back, calling the pope's comments "disgraceful.""

And he actually went a bit further then and called the pope a "pawn" of the Mexican government https://www.nbcnews.com/politics/2016-election/trump-calls-it-disgraceful-pope-question-his-christianity-n520841

Given that both parties got criticized, the upshot of mentioning the issue is probably limited.  Best to not remind people and trust in Catholics' tendency to ignore Church teachings when personally convenient (remember that contraception is also a doctrinal no-no ), rather than pick a fight with their belief system.

I suspect most pro-choice politicians have decided for years not to address the Catholic Church's position on this, and handle it in a secular manner.

I haven't been able to find the text of Pope Francis's remarks, but bible verses about "sojourners" (i.e. foreigners living temporarily in your country) can be found here. That website also has a similar list for abortion, but much or all of that list assumes that life begins at conception rather than at some point later (arguments about the correctness of that assumption are off topic. I merely note the assumption).
